# API Key storage in Ionic Securely

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I am developing an Ionic 4 Application and it requires making http call to consume data from an API.For the same , there is a need to add key with http request.
I want to know , how can I store api key securely , instead of putting it directly into service while building .apk for my application.
I presume , there is no concept of environment file which was there in Angular.
I have tried putting in API key in config.xml but not sure wether it is a good practice to put in api key in config file and also not aware of how to read the same from config file to service file.

Since , there are not much pointers available online, requesting to help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to inform, when you put anything in Angular's environment file it has 0 security since it's built into a build so that Angular uses it and therefore anyone with some level of interest in it may find all variables in compiled code.

Comment: is it a single API for every user or it's unique by user ?

Comment: If it's about key that relates to some external API (not provided by your system), then you have to make a kind of proxy using your server so that end user never receives this key (your server would call external API instead and return the results)

Comment: @Nicolas...It is a single api key geneic throughout application for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your **api_key** on the **server** and by using angular **APP_INITIALIZER** token you can call API to get api_key dynamically before app initializes and store them.

In this way, you can always handle your api_key via server. So if someone gets your code, he/she will not get your api_key.

Comment: But the API url will be in your code... so if someone gets your code, he/she can obtain your api key calling the url....